# Blackberry 10 network connectivity check

Tags: networking, blackberry-10

I am looking for a snip of code in Blackberry 10 that my device is connected with n/w or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official way is the [Wi-Fi Service](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/device_comm/wifi/cascades_wifi_overview.html) API, if you're familiar with C you should be good to go, look for any BPS tutorial/code online.

The unofficial and easier way is my class [WifiWatcher](https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/TheUnexposedAPIs/tree/master/src/WifiWatcher) from [TheUnexposedAPIs](https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/TheUnexposedAPIs), this project is a collection of easy-to-implement C++ classes that makes available all kind of internal objects from PPS (not to be confused with BPS).

You'll find an example of how to use it in QML in the project.

Comment: Thank you very much @Roger Leblanc for your support. I'll go through with your WifiWater. Last time when I was looking for WIFI connection programmatically we suggest me about WiFi service aggregator but you mentioned that even you also did not use it. I try to read it but having no luck. On the other hand API apparently saying its possible. Can you plz try it your end I am saying because it seems you are BB10 master :)

Comment: I've used BPS for some things in the past (ie: Battery Service), but never used BPS for Wi-Fi Service. All BPS are built the same way, so when you understand one, you can easily switch to another one. For Wi-Fi Service, there seems to be functions available to programmatically connect to a wifi hot-spot, I never tried that either. I don't have enough free time to try it on my own unfortunately.

Comment: Ok @Roger Leblanc I'll try it thanks to boost my confidence and for your support in my all questions.